# A probability problem

Tags: probability, card-games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Card probability problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145952/card-probability-problem)

The following question was asked on a closed online forum. I think the correct answer is `1/2`, however the original poster insists that it's `1/3`. What is the correct answer?

> I have 3 cards, one black on both sides, one red on both sides, and
>   one that is red on one side and black on the other. I shuffle the
>   cards, select one completely at random and hold it up to you. The side
>   of the card you see is red. What is the probability that the other
>   side of the card is black?
>
> - 1/3
> - 1/2
> - 2/3

Comment: Does shuffling also include changing which side is up?

Comment: @Egbert, no. (filler)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 1/2.  There are 3 card but 1 has both sides black.  So given the face you see is red only 2 cards are possible.  They are equally likely.  So the chance it is black is 1/2.