# Drawer probability problem

Tags: probability

A chest of drawers has 3 drawers. Each drawer has 2 boxes. The boxes of one drawer contain a silver coin in each respectively, the boxes of another a gold coin in each box, and the boxes of the third drawer a gold and a silver coin, respectively. A drawer is selected at random and a box from the drawer is selected at random and opened. The coin is found to be silver. What is the probability that the coin in the other box is gold?

I got 0.5.

Comment: How did you get 0.5?

Comment: The student is expected to show the working.

Comment: And yes, you are equally likely to select any particular drawer, *but* in each of those drawers there is a different probability for selecting the box containing a silver coin.  Given that you did select a silver coin, you are most likely to have selected the drawer containing the most silver coins.

Comment: [Very similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193851/whats-the-probability-that-the-other-side-of-the-coin-is-gold?rq=1).  Following the links, [here is essentially the problem you describe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187909/statistics-bertrands-box-paradox).

Comment: Don't be a jerk whoever you are doing the downvoting. He's obviously new here - cut him some slack!

Answer (score 0):

Each of the boxes was selected without bias (equal probability).   Three of these coins are silver; two of which share the same drawer with a silver coin (each other, in fact), while the third is paired with a gold coin.

Given that you did select one of these three silver coins, what then is the probability that it was the one paired with a gold coin?